# Better looking Tkinter File Dialogs for Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

In my application, the user needs to browse for files. However, the `askdirectory` from `tkFileDialog` isn't really comfortable for using and browsing files since it's somewhat outdated.
It looks like this:

[image]

What I want to achieve should look like the "default" windows browse dialog. Like this:

[image]

(Source https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-open-file-dialog/)

I am not sure (since I couldn't find proof) but I remember someone telling me that it looks like this because I am using Python 2.7 and not 3+.
Is that true? Does an alternative exist?

Comment: I think no. It doesn't exists

Comment: is there a particular reason as to why are you using `2.7`? also an alternative is to make one yourself

Comment: @Matiiss I don't have much of a choice right now since this is part of a big collaborative project. We do plan to move to python 3.8 somewhere in the future.

Comment: @RoyiLevy ok, actually I thought of one option just now, how about you install a newer version of python `Python 3.8` perhaps, go to the tkinter module and copy the source code of the file dialog, then adjust it to the `Python 2.7` needs?

Comment: @Matiiss how would I approach this? Never did anything like that. Is it possible to "take out" just that part?

Comment: @RoyiLevy I don't know either, haven't done that myself, but I would say there would be two parts, one is the general model that I think it has (basically the class it inherits from) and the class itself, then just change whatever doesn't go with 2.7, should be simple things? like `tkinter` to `Tkinter` and stuff, I don't know how the `2.7` version looks (as in code) so I can't tell ya exactly what has to be changed but basically try to make it run on 2.7 (what now runs on 3.8)

Answer (score 1):

It seems it has something to do with your version, as I have done a bit of research and I am using python 3 with the included tkinter and it shows a normal windows explorer popup. So, if you are using one of the up-to-date versions, it should be the OS' default. (I am unable to test that as python 2 will not work properly on my machine although I can confirm since you are using an older one)
I recreated your case with this code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

filedialog.askdirectory()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try using `askopenfilename()`. It displays the standard Open File dialog box.

For example:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog as fd

root = Tk()

root.title("Button to open files")
root.geometry("500x500")

def openfd(*args):
    askk = askopenfilename()

btn = Button(root, text="Click to open file", command=openfd)
btn.place(x=200, y=200)
root.mainloop()
```

You can read more about it at https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-open-file-dialog/.

Comment: That indeed looks better, although I need the user to select a folder and not a specific file. Also, the given example doesn't work in Python 2.7 as I need.

Comment: Oh, sorry...I didn't know it doesn't work in Python 2.7.